# Confusion on taylor series for complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been very confused when i start to learn about series in complex analysis, most probably due to the lack of understanding when i was learning real analysis on series.

Here is a problem, Find the Taylor series of $f(z) = e^{z}$ at $z=0$. So i follow the theorem and since $e^{z}$ is entire, we have $e^{z} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^k}{k!}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Now Find the Taylor series of $f(z) = e^{z}$ at $z = 1$. And by computing we get $e^z= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e(z-1)^k}{k!}$ for all $|z-1| < \infty$.

I am very confused as whether both power series are actually the same series?

And do both series converge to the same number?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call them the same series, but they are two Taylor series that represent the same function, namely $e^z$. And yes, both of them converge on all of $\mathbb{C}$ and take the same value (namely $e^z$). The only difference is really the point of convergence since it's an entire function. You might want to think about the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ once around $z_0 = 0$ and once around $z_0 = -1$ to see a difference in where it converges.

Comment: As a possible rough analogy, note that $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots$ and $\frac{9}{10} + \frac{9}{100} + \frac{9}{1000} + \cdots$ are different series that represent the same real number.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz: and also around $z_0=2$.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz what do u mean by point of convergence?? I thought that once it is a taylor series, it will always converge within the ball to e^z

Comment: By the uniqueness of power series of analytic functions both series have the same coefficients for $z^k$.

Comment: @ilovewt My bad, I meant the base point of your expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, as $e^z$ is entire all of its coefficients must be the same, but to see this explicitly, we find the $n$th coefficient,
\begin{align}[z^n] e^z &= [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e (z-1)^k}{k!}\\
&= [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} z^j(-1)^{k-j}
= \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{e}{k!}[z^n]\sum_{j=n}^k \binom{k}{j} z^j(-1)^{k-j}\\
&= e\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-n}}{k!} \binom{k}{n}
= e\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-n}}{k!} \frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}
= \frac{e}{n!} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-n}}{(k-n)!}\\
&= \frac{e}{n!} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!}
= \frac{e}{n!} e^{-1}
= \frac{1}{n!}
\end{align}

Comment: What about the case for $\dfrac{1}{1-z}$ when it expands say around $z_0 = 0$ and radius 1, and $z_0 = 2i$ and radius $sqrt{5}$?

Comment: The function $e^z$ is entire, and hence analytic everywhere, so its power series representation has an infinite radius of convergence. The series for $\frac{1}{1-z}$ around $z_0=0$ only has a radius of convergence of $1$, so you can only guarantee the uniqueness of coefficients in that neighborhood (i.e., points with $|z-0|<1$). $z_0=2i$ is not in that neighborhood as $|z_0|=2$, so you can't equate coefficients. There are exceptions, like removable discontinuities, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @adfriedman thanks for the crystal clear explanation!

Comment: Define the notation $[z^n]$.  It is not standard.

Comment: @Dr.MV I disagree. It is very basic and standard and common in formal power series, it is called the coefficient extraction operator. For instance, G. P. Egorychev, Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums.

Definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients